# Issue in dynamically adding row to the Table and setting value to the cells

Tags: codenameone

I have used a custom table model for adding rows dynamically to the table. My custom table model is -

```
public class CustomTableModel implements TableModel {

private ArrayList<Object[]> data;
private String[] columnNames;
private EventDispatcher dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
private boolean editable;

public CustomTableModel(String[] columnNames, Object[][] data) {
    this(columnNames, data, false);
}

public CustomTableModel(String[] columnNames, Object[][] data, boolean editable) {
    this.data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    for(Object[] o : data) {
        this.data.add(o);
    }
    this.columnNames = columnNames;
    this.editable = editable;
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

public String getColumnName(int i) {
    return columnNames[i];
}

public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return editable;
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    try {
        return data.get(row)[column];
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException err) {
        return "";
    }
}

public void setValueAt(int row, int column, Object o) {
    data.get(row)[column] = o;
    dispatcher.fireDataChangeEvent(column, row);
}

public void addDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener d) {
    dispatcher.addListener(d);
}

public void removeDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener d) {
    dispatcher.removeListener(d);
}

public void addRow(Object[] rowData, int row) {
    try {
        data.add(rowData);
        dispatcher.fireDataChangeEvent(0, row);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

variables used in table are -

```
// variables used in Table dataTable
     String[][] tableData = {
                     { "1", "2", "3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15"}
             };

            final CustomTableModel tableModel = new CustomTableModel (
                    new String[] { "","Density", "Volume Flow", "T (in)","T (out)","Flow", "Specific Heat", "Density", "Volume Flow", 
                            "T (in)","T (out)","Flow", "Specific Heat", "Duty", "UA"}, tableData,true);

            final String[] r =   { tableModel.getRowCount()+1+"", "2", "3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15"};
```

Table implementations is here -

```
    dataTable =  new Table(tableModel) {

        @Override
        protected Component createCell(Object value, final int row, final int column, boolean editable) {

            if(row == -1) {
                final Button headerButton = new Button((String)value);
                headerButton.setUIID(getUIID() + "Header");
                headerButton.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
                headerButton.getSelectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
                headerButton.setFlatten(true);
            }

            if(row >= 0) {

                if(column == 3 || column == 4 || column == 9 || column == 10) {
                    final Button cell = new Button((String)value);
                    cell.setUIID(getUIID() + "Cell");
                    cell.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
                    cell.getSelectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);

                    cell.setFlatten(true);
                    cell.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                            Container body  = new Container();
                            body.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                            Label value = new Label("Value");
                            value.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

                            TextField text = new TextField();
                            text.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
                            text.setText(cell.getText());
                            Label unit = new Label("Unit");
                            unit.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

                            ComboBox<String> uom = new ComboBox<String>();
                            uom.addItem("Celcius");
                            uom.addItem("Fahrenheit");
                            uom.addItem("Kelvin");
                            uom.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

                            body.addComponent(new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0), value);
                            body.addComponent(new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0), text);
                            body.addComponent(new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0), unit);
                            body.addComponent(new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0), uom);

                            Command cmd = Dialog.show("Add Values", body, new Command[] {new Command("OK")});

                            if(cmd.getCommandName().equals("OK")) {
                                tableModel.setValueAt(row, column, text.getText());
                            }

                            int totalRow = tableModel.getRowCount();
                            if(!(totalRow > row +1)) {
                                tableModel.addRow(r, row);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return cell;
                }

                if(column == 1 || column == 2 || column == 5 || column == 6 || column == 7 || column ==8 || column > 10) {

                    final Button cell = new Button((String)value);
                    cell.setUIID(getUIID() + "Cell");
                    cell.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
                    cell.getSelectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);

                    cell.setFlatten(true);
                    cell.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                            Container body  = new Container();
                            body.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                            Label value = new Label("Value");
                            value.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

                            TextField text = new TextField();
                            text.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
                            text.setText(cell.getText());
                            Label unit = new Label("Unit");
                            unit.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

                            ComboBox<String> uom = new ComboBox<String>();
                            uom.addItem("Celcius");
                            uom.addItem("Fahrenheit");
                            uom.addItem("Kelvin");
                            uom.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);

                            body.addComponent(new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0), value);
                            body.addComponent(new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0), text);
                            body.addComponent(new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0), unit);
                            body.addComponent(new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, GridBagConstraints.WEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0), uom);

                            Command cmd = Dialog.show("Add Values", body, new Command[] {new Command("OK")});

                            if(cmd.getCommandName().equals("OK")) {
                                tableModel.setValueAt(row, column, text.getText());
                            }

                            int totalRow = tableModel.getRowCount();
                            if(!(totalRow > row +1)) {
                                tableModel.addRow(r, row);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return cell;
                }

            } 



            Button cell = new Button("" + value);
            cell.setUIID(getUIID() + "Cell");
            cell.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
            cell.getSelectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
            cell.setFlatten(true);
            return cell;
        }
    };
```

If you see the in the above code,  condition to add row in the Table is -

```
if(!(totalRow > row +1)) {
        tableModel.addRow(r, row);
}
```

If I touch on any cell of last row of the Table, a dialog box will popup and on touching ok button it should add an extra row in the table. But what happening is -- first time touching ok button nothing happens and afterwards repeating this step, a row is added to the table. This happens recursively on every last row (added row).

Second issue is in below method of **CustomTableModel**

```
public void setValueAt(int row, int column, Object o) {
    data.get(row)[column] = o;
    dispatcher.fireDataChangeEvent(column, row);
}
```

When setting value to any cell, sometime it sets value to *other cells in the same column* as well.

Comment: We'll look into that.

Comment: Any resolution please?

Comment: Sorry it got buried under the list of tasks and I completely lost it. I'll try to get it reviewed/done over the weekend but keep an eye on this and remind me if I miss it!

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the original question containing the add/remove row to table and decided those approaches weren't very good so instead we fixed the [DefaultTableModel](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/table/DefaultTableModel.html) to support add/remove rows to the table.

This should "just work". It will be a part of the next plugin update or you can get it sooner by [working with the Codename One source code](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html).

Comment: Thanks. Waiting for next plugin update. When do we get new plugin update ( approx.) ?

Comment: We just released one last week so it might take a while. Probably before April.